# Determine the list of JVMs running on a remote machine on Linux platform

Tags: java, linux, rmi, jmx

I need to determine the list of JVMs running on a remote machine, and once that is done, to connect to each of the JVMs using JMX. I am a newbie and have gone through the following concepts:
1. using jps and jstat: I read that these commands may not be available in the future jdk versions.
2. using the java class "virtualmachine().list" . The problem with this though is that it helps you fetch the list of JVMs but only for the local machine. I do not know how to connect to a remote machine and then obtain this list.

Can anyone please suggest how to use either "virtualmachine().list" or any other method to obtain a list of JVMs on a remote machine ?

The problem is that all the methods(including the way jconsole works) that I have studied to connect to a remote JVM are focused to a SPECIFIC JVM where I need to provide the port number(of the JVM process). But I need a list of all the JVMs running. How can I do this ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: I feel it would be a bit of a security exposure to be able to get this list without some help in the remote machine. Therefore answers like hte one given by @monex0 might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to launch a small java application on the remote machine and have it run virtualmachine().list or similar and then send back the information or make it accessible using JMX.  This application could be running all the time, or you could maybe launch it remotely.

Some other ideas mentioned here: [Get System Information of a Remote Machine (Using Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135490/get-system-information-of-a-remote-machine-using-java).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion !!! This is indeed very interesting. The problem though is that there may be large number of remote machines and it maybe slightly inconvenient to launch applications on each of them. However, after going through the link you mentioned, I understand that this is probably the best we can do and also a direct info of the JVMs maybe IMPOSSIBLE. I guess that even if it were possible, like madth3 said, it may become a security issue. Please do let me know if my understanding is incorrect. Thank you !!

Comment: Well _impossible_ is a strong word.  There are always different ways to do things.  However, it seems that you have certain restrictions (like using only Java and connecting to random Linux servers). Another way would be to get shell access to the remote machine and run linux commands to get the information you need.  This seems like a lot of work and also has security consequences.

Comment: True. I did attempt shell access with linux commands, but for the same issues could not proceed with it. Like for instance, for every shell access the password had to be known, plus to connect to a particular JVM, another set of credentials. All of this had to be fetched, stored and then retrieved :( which is a great amount of work but more importantly a poor security measure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a java-agent or some other common component to each of the remote JVMs and have them "phone-home" their JMXServiceURLs to a central JVM clearing house. Other than that, I think your only options are derived broadly from [monex0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284420/monex0)'s suggestion.