# How to get remote machine OS information from JAVA?

Tags: java, rmi, remote-access, jcifs, netbios

Is there any way available to get the OS information (like OS name, version etc) of a remote machine from a java client. The machine is publicly accessible and also has the internet access. JAVA may not be installed in the remote machine. All the necessary credentials to access the machine is available.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135490/get-system-information-of-a-remote-machine-using-java

Comment: What do you mean by "All the necessary credentials to access the machine is available"? Do you mean the interactive Windows login? A local Unix account that is accessible through SSH? Either way, as the answer @Bazgrim pointed out, unless the remote server relays that information in some way to the client (and you would have to invent it), it's not generally possible unless you resort to hacking techniques (NetCat-style OS-fingerprinting, NetBIOS vulnerabilities, etc).